# Remove recessed lighting can

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, recessed-lighting

I am trying to remove a recessed lighting fixture (see photo below). This fixture was installed in the ceiling of a new addition in 1993 and I believe it is therefore a ‘new build’ type fixture rather than a retrofit.

I found similar threads which suggest that the solution is to pull the trim down hard and twist at the same time. I have tried this and the fitting moves a 1/4 inch away from the drywall but no further. The result is the same when the 3 tiny metal tabs on the inside of the can are pushed in. I believe this is a Lightolier fitting but I don’t have the model number. It may be secured to the joists by a frame, but I think it should still be possible to remove the can itself?

I would be very grateful for any suggestions on how to remove it without using metal cutters!

[image]

Comment: Can you gain access to the fixture from above?

Comment: sorry - forgot to mention that this fixture is in a cathedral ceiling with no access from above.

Comment: Please [merge your guest and registered accounts](/help/merging-accounts), which will allow you to [edit](/help/privileges/create-posts), [comment on](/help/privileges/comment) any of your posts and [accept an answer](/help/someone-answers) on your question. Thanks, and welcome to the site!